# How add composables provided by nuxt module to auto import?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt-module

I would like to add composables from my custom nuxt module and use them in components without import.

Now I have to use #import because without it I get an error (500 - useTest is not defined). I have something like this, any ideas how I can achieve this?

```js
// src/module.ts
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import {
  defineNuxtModule,
  addPlugin,
  createResolver,
  addComponent,
  addImportsDir,
} from "@nuxt/kit";

export interface ModuleOptions {
  addPlugin: boolean;
}

export default defineNuxtModule<ModuleOptions>({
  meta: {
    name: "my-module",
    configKey: "myModule",
  },
  defaults: {
    addPlugin: true,
  },
  setup(options, nuxt) {
    const { resolve } = createResolver(import.meta.url);
    const runtimeDir = fileURLToPath(new URL("./runtime", import.meta.url));

    addImportsDir(resolve(runtimeDir, "composables"));
  },
});
```

```js
// src/runtime/composables/useTest.ts
export function useTest() {
  console.log("run useTest");

  return {
    test: () => {
      console.log("run test method provided by useTest");
    },
  };
}
```

```js
// playground/app.vue
<template>
  <div>
    Nuxt module playground!
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useTest } from "#imports"; // <--------- I would like remove this line
useTest();
</script>
```

Comment: did you find a workaround for this, having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I opened an issue on GitHub about this and here's the solution:

https://github.com/nuxt/starter/issues/261

> You are experiencing this in the module starter because we
> deliberately disable auto-imports while developing a module:
>
> https://github.com/nuxt/starter/blob/module/.nuxtrc#L1
>
> The issue was that auto-imports won't work in node_modules so it was
> very easy for module authors to rely on auto-imports in their runtime
> code when developing their module.

**Current workaround:**

To get it to work just edit `.nuxtrc` and change `imports.autoImport=false` to `imports.autoImport=true`

a pr has been approved to update the documentation: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/pull/19219

Comment: But there are no `.nuxtrc` in a current Nuxt version: `3.10`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I don't know why addImportsDir not work as expected. Here my workaround:

```
export default defineNuxtModule<ModuleOptions>({
  meta: {
    name: "my-module",
    configKey: "myModule",
  },
  defaults: {
    addPlugin: true,
  },
  setup(options, nuxt) {
    const { resolve } = createResolver(import.meta.url);
    const runtimeDir = fileURLToPath(new URL("./runtime", import.meta.url));

    // addImportsDir(resolve(runtimeDir, "composables"));

    nuxt.hook('nitro:config', (nitroConfig) => {
      if (!nitroConfig.imports) {
        nitroConfig.imports = {
          imports: [],
        };
      }

      nitroConfig.imports.imports.push({
        name: 'useTest',
        as: 'useTest',
        from: join(runtimeDir, 'composables/useTest'),
      });
    });
  },
});
```

Comment: this solution return this error for me [vite-node] [plugin:nuxt:imports-transform] [VITE_ERROR] /app.vue